# Integral-Summation Problem (Mathematical Physics problem)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

given,     $ψ_{k}$ =$\sqrt{\frac{2}{q}}$ $\sin \frac{kπx}{q}$

we have, $g_{kj}$=$q\int^q_0 ψ_j\frac{\partial ψ_k}{\partial q} dx$

verify, $\sum_{k}g_{jk}g_{lk}=q^2\int^q_0 \frac{\partial ψ_j}{\partial q}\frac{\partial ψ_l}{\partial q}dx$

My approach :
take the derivative of $g_{kj}$ with respect to q after dividing both sides by q,we have

-$\frac{g_{kj}}{q^2}=\int^q_0 ψ_j\frac{\partial^2 ψ_k}{\partial q^2} dq+\int^q_0 \frac{\partial ψ_j}{\partial q}\frac{\partial ψ_l}{\partial q}dx$

Here I'm stuck.

2nd approach: put the expression of  $g_{kj}$ in 3rd Eqn., we have

$\sum_{k}(q\int^q_0 ψ_k\frac{\partial ψ_j}{\partial q} dx)(q\int^q_0 ψ_k\frac{\partial ψ_l}{\partial q} dx)=q^2\int^q_0 \frac{\partial ψ_j}{\partial q}\frac{\partial ψ_l}{\partial q}dx$

Again I'm stuck.